# OpenEDX-Insights - Token error: Invalid issuer

Tags: django, openedx

I have a devstack OpenEDX Dogwood.3 running. 
I installed Analytics as a FullStack (Ubuntu 12.04). I followed this link : https://openedx.atlassian.net/wiki/display/OpenOPS/edX+Analytics+Installation.

But when I am trying to connect on analytics I have this error :

File "/edx/app/insights/venvs/insights/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/backends/open_id.py", line 341, in validate_and_return_id_token
    raise AuthTokenError(self, err)
AuthTokenError: Token error: Invalid issuer

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to modify do the next:

1. Create new client in lms.domain/admin/oauth2/client/

**Name:** insights

**Url:** insights.domain:18110

**Redirect uri:** insights.domain:18110/complete/edx-oidc/

Save the autogenerated **Client id** and **Client secret** to use it later.

2. Select the created client from:

   lms.domain/admin/oauth2_provider/trustedclient/
3. In your LMS box

modify */edx/app/lms.env.json* and */edx/app/cms.env.json*

to:

**"OAUTH_ENFORCE_SECURE":** false,

**"OAUTH_OIDC_ISSUER":** "lms.domain/oauth2",

in "FEATURES": { add

**"ENABLE_OAUTH2_PROVIDER":** true

4. In your insights Box

*/edx/etc/insights.yml*

SOCIAL_AUTH_EDX_OIDC_ID_TOKEN_DECRYPTION_KEY: **Client secret**

SOCIAL_AUTH_EDX_OIDC_ISSUER: **lms.domain/oauth2**

SOCIAL_AUTH_EDX_OIDC_KEY: **Client id**

SOCIAL_AUTH_EDX_OIDC_SECRET: **Client secret**

SOCIAL_AUTH_EDX_OIDC_URL_ROOT: **lms.domain/oauth2**

5. RESTART SERVICES

LMS

sudo /edx/bin/supervisorctl restart edxapp:

INSIGHTS

/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart insights

/edx/bin/supervisorctl restart analytics_api